# How can I efficiently compute the md5 sum of an iterable of bits in Python?

Tags: python, hash, md5, generator, bitarray

Consider the code below. It converts an image to line art and then computes the md5sum of the bits. I don't know a better to do this than with a generator expression producing individual bits. But then how can I feed the result to md5 in an efficient way?

The code below does it with a [bitarray](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/) object, but I get non-deterministic results handing `bitarray` instances (which seem to use fancy C stuff under the hood) to md5. So what is the "right" way to do this?

```
import os, hashlib
from PIL import Image
from bitarray import bitarray

def image_pixel_hash_code(image):
    pixels = list(image.getdata())
    avg = sum(pixels) / len(pixels)
    bits = bitarray(pixel < avg for pixel in pixels)
    return hashlib.md5(bits).hexdigest()


im = Image.open(os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/test.jpg")).convert("L")
print image_pixel_hash_code(im)
```

P.S. I can reproduce the bitarray non-determinism but I assumes it's just a function of using two things together that aren't supposed to work together.

Comment: As long as the interfacing from one thing to the other is done correctly, there's no reason they won't work together. `bitarray` doesn't produce non-deterministic results, it would be useless if it did. BTW, you could simplify things a little with `bits = bitarray(pixel < avg for pixel in pixels)`.

Comment: @martineau, I've made your code improvement, thanks. And John has solved the mystery of non-determinism (I needed to pad with zeroes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hash is including random bits at the end of `bits` if the length of `bits` is not a multiple of 8.

You can see this by looking at `memoryview(bits)`

You could fix this by padding `bits` with `0`s

```
    bits = bitarray(1 if pixel < avg else 0 for pixel in pixels)
    bits.fill()
    return hashlib.md5(bits).hexdigest()
```

Comment: Thanks! I especially appreciate the pointers to `memoryview` and `fill`. Would I be right to infer that now that bitarray is behaving this approach is reasonably efficient?

Comment: kuzzooroo: It's difficult to say if this is "efficient". It computes the md5 by summing fewer values, but required a fair amount of processing to produce them. Only timing it would determine if it's faster than some alternative. It should be noted that a major side-effect of using this method is that it is less likely to detect image differences than applying md5 to all the raw data in the image would — if that's what you're using it to do.